# WP Как выводить дату обновления для таксономии?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть ли возможность в WordPress выводить время когда была обновлена категория (кастомная) ? Пробовал так

```
<p class="vendor_box__time">Последнее обновление рубрики: 
<time datetime="<?php the_modified_date('c'); ?>"><?php the_modified_date('j.m.Y'); ?></time>
</p>
```

Не работает. Оно вообще куда-то пишет данные в базе?

Comment: WP не хранит дату последнего обновления таксономий, функция `the_modified_date()` работает только с пост тайпами. Если нужно, то данный функционал можно реализовать и хранить дату например в term meta.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. А как это можно подключить ?

Comment: А по какому принципу должно быть ясно что таксономия обновилась? В том смысле что это может быть обновление какого-то описания самой таксономии, либо обновилась запись в таксономии и следственно таксономию тоже можно считать обновленной.

Comment: Хммм, хороший вопрос. По сути у  меня костомная таксономия в которую я добавил произвольные поля генерируемые плагином ACF. И вот изменения любого из этих полей привязаного к данной таксономии хотел бы считать Обновлением рубрики.